# Estimating value of sum of products using of two variables using Central Limit Theorem.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Consider this distirbution,

$S=a_0\cdot b_0 + a_1\cdot b_1 + a_2\cdot b_2 + \cdots +a_{n-1}\cdot b_{n-1}$

Now, I want find the expected value of $S$ when, $a_i$'s are selected from $\{0,1\}$ with equal probability. And $b_i$'s are uniformly selected from $[-1/2,1/2]$. All values are i.i.d.

According to my calculation,
$\mu_a=0\ \&\ \mu_b=0$, $E[a^2]=1/2\ \&\ E[b^2]=(b-a)^2/12=1/12$

As mean is zero in the combined distribution, the variance of the joint distribution is $E[a^2\cdot b^2]=E[a^2]E[b^2]=1/24$.
Hence, the variance of $S=n/24$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{n/24}$.

Now, in this [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/839.pdf) (page 9), the authors say that

> Each entry of the vector $Ws$ is a sum of $n$ (or around $n/2$ in the case where $s \in \{0, 1\}^n$) rational numbers in the interval $[−1/2, 1/2]$. Assuming the entries of $W$ are uniformly distributed then the central limit theorem suggests that each entry of $Ws$ has an absolute value roughly $1/4\sqrt{n/2}$.

I did not understand how the authors arrived at this value.

It is to be noted that the values of $W$ are sampled uniformly from $[-1/2,1/2]$ similar to the $b_i$'s and the values of $s$ is sampled from $\{0,1\}$ with equal probability similar to the $a_i$'s.

Also, In section 2.1 the authors say that the expected value (Euclidean norm) of a $n$ dimensional vector sampled from a discrete Gaussian distribution with s.d $\sigma$ is $\sqrt{n}\sigma$. So, according to the authors, $S$ is a summation $n/2$ values ($b_i$) sampled uniformly from $[−1/2, 1/2]$, so can we say that central limit theorem guarantees that the distribution of $b_i$ follow a Gaussian distribution with $\sigma=1/4$?
I appreciate your help.

EDIT : $\mu_a$ will be $1/2$ and not $0$. But it still does not solve the issue. as $\mu_a \cdot \mu_b=0$

Comment: The general idea of using the CLT seems OK, but some of your statements
puzzle me: (a) Isn't $E(a_i) = \mu_a = E(a_i^2) = 1/2(0) + 1/2(1) = 1/2?$ 
(b) What are the entries of $W.$ (It's unfair to ask me to read the whole
paper, which presumably you have done.)  (c) Am I correct that the $a_i$'s are symmetrical Bernoulli's (discrete) and that $b_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathsf{Unif}(-.5,.5)$ (continuous)? (d) What do you mean by the 'value' of a vector?

Comment: @BruceET I thank you for your time and I apologize for the confusions. I will clarify them here, a) Yes you are right, I miscalculated the mean,  b) the entries of $W$ is uniformly sampled from $[-/5,.5]$ c)You are right about $a_i$, each entry of $a_i$ can assume $0$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$. $b_i$ is also correct. d) by the value of a vector I mean the Euclidean norm. $|| \cdot ||_2$. I have made corrections in question.

Comment: So, it seems clear that $SD(S) = \sigma = \sqrt{n/24}.$ I suppose your edit is an improvement, but exactly what remains unresolved? $W$ is not $S.$

Comment: @BruceET I don't understand authors arrived at the different value from mine (the paper was accepted in a reputed peer reviewed conference). I don't understand who is right?

Comment: You say "...according to the authors, $S$ is a summation $n/2$ values ($b_i$) sampled uniformly from $[−1/2, 1/2]$," In fact, _on average_ $S$ is a summation of $n/2$ of such uniforms. I don't know which is wrong, their statement or your interpretation of it. You know the right answer to the the Question you pose (variance of $S$). Suggest you read the paper more carefully to make sure of your interpretation of $W.$ And if the authors or wrong, it would hardly be the first such instance in a 'reputable refereed journal'..

Comment: @BruceET I think my interpretation is same as the authors. The authors say $S$ is a summation of $n/2$ values from $[-1/,1/2]$ because of the equal probability distribution of $\{0,1\}$. I have factored this into my calculation

Comment: There is a difference btw _exactly_ $n/2$ and an _avg_ of $n/2.$ Another model is N ~ Binom(20..5), $X_i$ iid Unif(-.5,.5), and $S = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$. Maybe google "Random sum or random variables." Simulated that with same result for $V(S).$ I see no question about E(S) and V(S) as you have defined S. Questions are whether you understand conf proc article and whether it is correct. Done here before we get busted for ''chatting' in Comments.

Comment: @BruceET Thank you for your help. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comment continued:*  Assuming my guesses in (c) of my Comment are correct,
here is a simulation of a million sums $S$ for $n = 20.$ By part (a)
of my Comment, you
should have $E(S) = 0.$ Also,
you say you should have $\sigma = \sqrt{20/24} =  0.9128709,$ which is
approximately confirmed by the simulation. For large $n,$ you will have
$S$ *nearly* (but not exactly) normal. It seems that $n = 20$ is large
enough to get a good approximation to normality.

```
m = 10^6;  s = numeric(m);  n = 20
for(i in 1:m) {
  a = rbinom(n, 1, .5);  b = runif(n, -.5,.5)
  s[i] = sum(a*b) }
mean(s);  sd(s)
## -0.0004134797    # aprx E(S) = 0 
## 0.9128541        # aprx SD(S) = 0.9128709
```

The histogram below shows the approximate distribution of $S$ from simulation
together with the well-fitting density function of $\mathsf{Norm}(0, .9129).$

[image]

Of course, the simulation doesn't 'prove' anything, but its results may
encourage you that you are mainly on the right track. You should be able to clarify your statement of the problem and write a convincing
solution for general $n$.